# How to avoid that "x0d" is interpreted as a newline character?

Tags: python, c#, character-encoding, newline, packed-decimal

I have to send a file to the mainframe and generate some numeric values in packed decimal format. The problem is that in some cases, the value in the file generates a new line and I need it in the same line. After conversion to a packed decimal, the value -10 becomes "x01x0d". The "x0d" at the end is lost because it was interpreted as a newline character ('\n'). Is it possible to prevent this character from being interpreted as a newline?

I tried to change the encoding to cps500 (in python) instead of utf-8, but it didn't work. I would like to have a tip that allows me to give this information to the mainframe properly.

I made python programa with the example I'm facing. note that every time a call the function "pack_number" passing a negative value and print the result, the line breaks in a new one.

```
from array import array
from struct import pack

def pack_number(valor, tam, qtdecasasdecimais):
    """ Pack a COMP-3 number. Format: PIC 9(tam)V9(qtdecasasdecimais). """
     # qtde de casas decimais nao pode ser maior que o tamanho do campo
    if qtdecasasdecimais > tam:
        qtdecasasdecimais = tam

    valor *= 10 ** qtdecasasdecimais
    tam_packed = int((tam + 1) / 2) + (tam + 1) % 2

    #print (tam_packed)
    valor = int(valor)

    # Is the number negative?  Remember for later.
    negative = False
    if valor < 0:
        negative = True
        valor *= -1

    # Treat the number as a string.  Makes it easier to loop over.
    n_str = str(valor)
    b = int(n_str[0])

    # For each digit, shift it onto the result.
    for c in n_str[1:]:
        b = (b << 4) | int(c)

    # Make the number negative if needed.
    if negative:
        b = (b << 4) | 0xD
    else:
        b = (b << 4) | 0xc

    # calling pack_number()
    b_packed = pack('>q', b)
    if len(b_packed) > tam_packed:
        b_packed = b_packed[-1 * tam_packed:]

    return b_packed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('arquivo.bin', 'wb') as pdd:
        for linhas in range(1, 11):
            pdd.write(pack_number( linhas, 7, 2))
            pdd.write(pack_number( -1 * linhas, 7, 2))
        pdd.close()
```

Comment: Did you open the file in binary mode? If not, and you're on Windows, you're subject to line ending conversion. More information about exactly what you are doing, perhaps with a [mcve], would be helpful.

Comment: "binary file" and "utf-8" in one statement does not make much sense... Please [edit] the question to provide exact expected/actual content of a **sample** file as hex. Include code you wrote (consider tagging the question with just one language - C# and python are quite different to have single answer for both).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: base64 encode your binary string ... as there is no `\n` in that alphabet ... (or make up your own encoding or whatever...) the point is that 0x0d is a newline no matter what, so you cannot send that byte (as a byte) and have it be anything other than a new line (so to avoid that you must encode it into a different representation(ie base64))

Comment: If you need to be sure the byte you send (because of protocol), use binary. We can still use ASCII characters to represent numbers for convenience (most hardware protocol uses such ideas, not just values). If you think you have a text string (you care less about values), use text. Keep it clear on coding which layer you use in which functions (do not mix it: it will be an expensive optimization).

Comment: I included a python code as an example of the problem I'm facing